# Bedeutung des Wortes "apokryph"

Tags: meaning

Lt. [Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/apokryph) hat das Wort zwei Bedeutungen. Die erste ("zu den Apokryphen gehörend") ist mir bekannt.

Meine Frage ist, ob man die zweite Bedeutung ("zweifelhaft; nicht zum Gültigen, Anerkannten gehörend; unecht") im folgenden Kontext anwenden kann:

Eine (christliche) Person vertritt die Auffassung, eine Ehefrau sei Dienerin ihres Mannes, sie braucht und soll nicht arbeiten, weil das Männersache ist und sie sich um Haushalt und Kinder zu kümmern hat, etc. Begründet wird dies ausschließlich mit Worten aus der Bibel.

Ist es korrekt, zu sagen, die besagte Person vertritt "**apokryphe**" Ansichten?

(Ein studierter Theologe hat dieses Wort in diesem Zusammenhang genau so verwendet. Mir persönlich scheint diese Verwendung zwar nicht absurd, aber doch sehr befremdlich und ziemlich weit hergeholt - daher die Frage...)

https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/apokryph

Comment: Dann ist der Ausdruck "apokryphe Ansichten vertreten" vielleicht selbst apokryph ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Das Wort *apokryph* wird vom Duden hier recht dämlich erklärt, aber auch [DWDS macht es nicht besser](https://www.dwds.de/wb/apokryph), denn beide beschreiben das Wort nur unzureichend in seiner Bedeutung.

> [Apokryphen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apokryphen) (auch apokryphe Schriften; altgr. ἀπόκρυφος apokryphos **,verborgen‘**, ‚dunkel‘; Plural ἀπόκρυφα apokrypha) sind religiöse Schriften jüdischer bzw. christlicher Herkunft aus der Zeit zwischen etwa 200 vor und 400 nach Christus, **die nicht in einen biblischen Kanon** aufgenommen wurden oder über deren Zugehörigkeit Uneinigkeit besteht, sei es aus inhaltlichen oder religionspolitischen Gründen, oder weil sie erst nach Abschluss des Kanons entstanden sind oder zur Zeit seiner Entstehung nicht allgemein bekannt waren.

Vom griechischen kommend vertritt der Herr Bibelmaskulinist also angeblich entweder *verborgene* Ansichten, die obendrein nicht anerkannt werden, oder der Beschuldigte zitiert eben gar nicht aus der kanonischen Literatur der Bibel selbst.

Dies würde bedeuten, eine halbwegs 'korrekte' Verwendung des Zitats läge vermutlich vor, mit der Einschränkung, dass zwar biblische Texte aber eben keine keine Bibeltexte als Beleg genutzt werden.

Nun müsste geklärt werden, welche Apokryphen zur genannten Begründung zitiert werden, um die genaue Bedeutung dieses Theologenzitats zu bestimmen. Da diese Art der Exegese Theologen liegt, Ottonormalrednern aber weniger, sollte man schlicht davon ausgehen, dass ein Theologe sowohl Bibelkanonhistorie studiert hat, als auch Griechisch, und daher wohl eher zur etymologisch näherliegenden Bedeutung tendiert, so wie andere Verwender dieses Wortes auch:

> [Das Adjektiv apokryph bedeutet „nicht anerkannt“, „zweifelhaft“.](https://neueswort.de/apokryph/)
>
> Als apokryph wurden zunächst die Apokryphen bezeichnet, also Texte mit christlichen Inhalten, die aber nicht in den Bibelkanon aufgenommen wurden. Inzwischen kann der Begriff auch verwendet werden, um andere Arten von Texten und Aussagen zweifelhaften Ursprungs oder zweifelhaften Inhalts zu beschreiben.
>
> Ursprung ist das altgriechische apokryphos (verborgen).
>
> Bisherige Berichte über IS-Terroristen, die sich unter die syrischen Flüchtlinge mischen, sind apokryph.
>
> Auf seinem Totenbett wurde Niccolö Machiavelli bedrängt, den Teufel und all dessen Werke zu verfluchen „Dies ist nicht der Zeitpunkt, sich Feinde zu machen“, erwiderte er, lehnte sich in sein Kissen zurück und verschied. Der Hergang ist so nicht verbürgt, die Anekdote apokryph.
> – Die Zeit (1984), Der Fürst, 1.6.1984 Nr. 23.

Wenn der Adressat dieses Ausspruchs also selbst ein Theologe ist oder als entsprechend gebildeter Mensch anzusehen wäre, könnte eine religiös-theologische, inhaltliche Kritik am Gesagten damit ausgedrückt worden sein.
In Alltagssituationen ohne Vorkenntnisse über den Adressaten scheint die Tendenz eher in Richtung "abwegig, crazy, Minderheitenmeinung, Aussenseiterposition" zu gehen.

Falls im gerade gelesenen Text oder irgendwo auf dieser Seite  im Zusammenhang die Wörter wie 'falsch' oder 'richtig' auftauchen, bitte ich um Nachsicht für den ursprünglichen Verwender des Wortes "apokryph": da geht es weniger um diese Dichotomie von richtig oder falsch, sondern darum, ob das was kommuniziert werden soll auch effektiv, also verständlich kommuniziert wurde.

Wenn der Kritisierte seine Meinung mit Stellen aus dem 4. Makkabäerbuch und dem Thomasevangelium herleitet, dann ist die Verwendung von "apokryph" erstmal naheliegend.
Wenn dann diese Ansichten mit offiziellem Dogma der Kirche oder politischer Position des nächstgelgenen Bischofs inkompatibel ist, dann ist "apokryph" 'korrekt' im Sinne von "diese Ansicht ist genauso wenig anerkannt wie Tobit bei den Evangelischen.
Wenn der Theologe meint, die Ansichten des Maskulinisten ließen sich nicht folgerichtig aus den Perikopen ableiten, dann wäre "apokryph" etwas schief verwendet, denn die Ansichten des Kritisierten scheinen offen zu Tage zu liegen. Es wäre aber auch möglich, dass der Kritisierte seine Ansichten eben nur scheinbar offen ausspricht, also ganz gnostisch eine vertiefte Bedeutung damit kommunizieren will (analog zu Whistle words, virtu signalling). Dann wäre apokryph äußerst treffend verwendet, aber recht schwierig auf Anhieb so zu verstehen.

Noch einmal [Verwendungsbeispiele](https://www.dwds.de/wb/apokryph):

> Mir war das alles lange zu geschmäcklerisch, zu apokryph und auch zu aufgeputzt.
> *Die Welt, 22.12.2004*
> Die Künstler nutzen die neue Freiheit und schöpfen ungeniert aus den als häretisch verbotenen apokryphen Quellen.
> *Die Zeit, 25.12.1992, Nr. 53*
> In der Praxis sind apokryphe Bildungen und Ausweichmanöver die Folge.
> *Böckenförde, Ernst-Wolfgang: Die Organisationsgewalt im Bereich der Regierung, Berlin: Duncker u. Humblot 1964, S. 62*
> Die apokryphe Überlieferung versteht Joh 20, 27 als Auszeichnung des Apostels, dem es als einzigem gewährt war, den Auferstandenen zu berühren.
> *Bartsch, H.-W.: Thomas. In: Die Religion in Geschichte und Gegenwart, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2000 [1962], S. 8562*
> Anna-Szenen zurücktreten, wird die G. M. - von apokryphen Stoffen begleitet - weiter dargestellt.
> *o. A.: Lexikon der Kunst - G. In: Olbrich, Harald (Hg.), Lexikon der Kunst, Berlin: Directmedia Publ. 2001 [1989], S. 1457*

Gemäß Duden wäre nur eine einzige Verwendung der genannten Beispiele "richtig". Ich schließe daraus, dass der Duden den Leuten bei weitem nicht genau genug und auch nicht großzügig wie präzise genug auf's Maul geschaut hat.

Es bleibt unklar, was der zitierte Theologe genau gesagt haben will. Die Möglichkeiten, die sich ergeben, wenn man von einer bewussten und zutreffenden Verwendung auszugehen hat, sind recht zahlreich.

Sofern mit dem Wort "apokryph" die Ansichten als abwegig, crazy, wenig angesehen, selten, Minderheitenmeinung, Aussenseiterposition etc gemeint waren, lautet das Urteil: ja, die besagte Person vertritt "apokryphe" Ansichten!

Answer (score 9):

Über die Korrektheit dieser Verwendung kann man sicherlich streiten.
(Ich kenne "apokryph" bisher ausschließlich in der Bedeutung, die im Englischen mit "not canon" ausgedrückt wird. Etwa wenn in Biographien nicht belegbare Anekdoten erwähnt werden -- ich würde darum auch die zweite Duden-Definition enger auslegen: zweifelhaft, von der Quellenlage nicht gestützt. Hier gibt's aber sicher abweichende Meinungen.)

Das Problem hier sehe ich eher darin, dass das Wort für den gegebenen **Kontext** eine extrem unglückliche Wahl ist. Um eine Meinung zu kommentieren, die ihrerseits mit (nicht-apokryphen<sup>Bedeutung [1]</sup>) Bibelstellen begründet wird, sollte gerade ein Theologe vielleicht ein anderes Wort wählen. ("Absurd" bietet sich an.)

Answer (score 6):

Korrekt ist es, wird aber nur von Fachleuten verstanden, die anderen müssen nachschlagen.

Wer gemeinverständlich schreiben will, sollte das Wort austauschen, z. B. gegen »zweifelhaft«, »fragwürdig«, »dubios«, »anachronistisch« oder »überholt«.

Answer (score 3):

Bei Fremdwörter ist immer zu unterscheiden zwischen der Bedeutung, die sich aus der Übersetzung ins Deutsche ergibt, und der Bedeutung, mit der das Wort tatsächlich verwendet wird.

Als Beispiel möchte ich die beiden Wörter *»**Atom**«* (von altgriechisch *ἄτομος*, Transliteration *átomos*) und *»**Individuum**«* (von lateinisch *individuum*) anführen. Beide Wörter bedeuten, wenn man sie ins Deutsche übersetzt, dasselbe, nämlich *»**das Unteilbare**«*. Aber sie werden nicht mit dieser Bedeutung verwendet.

Tatsächlich sind diese Bedeutungen gängig:

- Atom = Bausteine, aus denen alle Materialien bestehen.
- Individuum = Ein bestimmter Mensch, der sich von anderen Menschen unterscheidet.

Das altgriechische Wort *απόκρυφος (apokryphos)* bedeutet, wenn man es ins Deutsche übersetzt, *geheim, versteckt, verborgen* oder *unbekannt*. Man findet auch die Übersetzungen *obskur, okkult, mysteriös*, die aber selbst Fremd- oder Lehnwörter sind, deren Bedeutungen ohnehin von den bereits genannten deutschen Wörtern abgedeckt werden.

Tatsächlich wird das Wort aber praktisch ausschließlich verwendet, um religiöse Texte zu bezeichnen, die gemeinsam mit den Texten der Bibel entstanden sind, und die auch ähnliche Themen behandeln, die aber nicht in die Bibel aufgenommen wurden. Die Texte, die in die Bibel aufgenommen wurden, nennt man *»kanonisch«* (Beispielsweise werden der Ochs und der Esel, die neben der Krippe in Betlehem gestanden sein sollen, nur in apokryphen Schriften erwähnt, in der Bibel findet man diese Tiere nicht.)

**Daher:**

Die Behauptung, eine Ehefrau wäre die Dienerin ihres Mannes, als apokryph zu bezeichnen, ist ...

- **falsch** in Sinn der Bedeutung des altgriechischen Wortes,
  denn diese Behauptung ist weder *geheim*, noch *versteckt, verborgen* oder *unbekannt*.
- **falsch** in Sinn der Bedeutung von nicht-kanonisch,
  denn es handelt sich hier um keinen religiösen Text aus der Eisenzeit.

Comment: Die Auffassung, eine Ehefrau sei Dienerin ihres Mannes, dürfte im Gegenteil aus dem Bibel-Kanon ableitbar sein (Epheser 5:22). Eine historisch-kritische Bibelauslegung wird diese Auffassung zwar nicht mehr unterstützen, aber es wundert mich schon, dass ausgerechnet ein Theologe in diesem Kontext das Wort "apokryph" verwendet.